# launch a python program with it's arguments on cmd and get the output messages python

Tags: python

I would like to launch a python program.exe to test it from another python code i,e launch it on the cmd (myprogram.exe -a arg1 -b arg2) and eventually get the error message it can print or any console output

does anyone have an idea how to do this?
thanks

EDIT

Actually I launch it with os.popen(command) but what I want is to know if it ended with sys.exit or any exception or if it ended normally

PS:I'm running python 2.6 (can't use subprocess.check_output )

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am not clear about your question, but if you want to run the exe from another python program you could use subprocess module.

```
import subprocess
command = "myprog.exe -a arg1 -b arg2"
result = subprocess.check_output(command.split())
print result
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer .. i'm running python 2.6 and subprocess.check_output doesn't work on it

Comment: Sorry for the delay, try os.system or subprocess.call

Answer (score 0):

You can run any python command from cmd using `Python.exe -c //code`

For example, `Python.exe -c print(10*10)` will print `100` to your console.

Does this help? Your question is a little unclear, sorry.